# Ejabberd mod_archive_odbc compilation error

Tags: compiler-errors, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mod-archive-odbc

I am trying to add support for saving chat messages on server side for my ejabberd server. But I am unable to compile the mod_archive_odbc module thus no beam file is being created.
I have downloaded the source file from git and trying to build it using its batch file provided for compilation. The server is running on windows. Following the command line output from compilation:

```
***./mod_archive_odbc.erl:366: undefined macro 'ERROR_MSG/2'
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:489: undefined macro 'ERROR_MSG/2'
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:867: undefined macro 'ERROR_MSG/2'
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2408: undefined macro 'ERROR_MSG/2'
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2428: undefined macro 'ERROR_MSG/2'
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:73: function process_local_iq/3 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:249: function should_store_jid/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:255: function do_log/12 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:328: function process_local_iq/3 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:330: function process_local_iq/3 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:332: function process_local_iq/3 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:383: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:386: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:389: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:393: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:647: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:728: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:838: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:928: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1018: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1035: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1122: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1129: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1138: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1154: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1190: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1238: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1248: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1314: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1332: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1341: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1371: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1378: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1413: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1416: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1420: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1460: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1466: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1473: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1571: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1573: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1575: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1699: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1705: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1713: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1750: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1763: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1810: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1877: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1883: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1957: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:1965: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2035: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2068: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2079: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2152: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2178: function run_sql_query/1 undefined
./mod_archive_odbc.erl:2183: function run_sql_transaction/2 undefined
```

and some more warnings.
Please help

Comment: Can you give a link to the source file you are trying to compile?

Comment: I am having the same problem. using the data from github.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It seems that mod_archive_odbc depends on a file called ejabberd.hrl . I googled and found the file online. Copy this file to the `src` directory.

https://github.com/ajaxorg/mod_rdb/blob/master/ejabberd.hrl

Try to build again and this should work.